# Bash exec + chmod incomprehensive argument

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

here is a simple script that I don't really understand:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read s; do
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no (connection to my servers) 'sudo find /path/to/main/directory -type f -exec chmod 755 {} +'
done < hosts_to_change.txt
```

without the + at the command it says chmod: missing operand after ‘755’. Could someone explain why I need to use the '+' and 755 is not enough?

Comment: See `man 1 find`, `-exec ... {} +` syntax.

Comment: After examining closely I'm surprised: I would expect `find` to complain with `missing argument to '-exec'` and never run `chmod` in the first place. Oh well, maybe the implementation of `find` you're using is somewhat strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-exec chmod 755 {} +` executes the `chmod` command on the selected regular files in an optimized manner.

Rather than executing `chmod` on each individual selected file, the command line is built by appending each selected filename to the end of the command line in much the same way that `xargs` builds its command lines.

This means that the total number of invocations of the `chmod` command will typically be much less than the number of matched files.